# Have skype notify me only when some people go online?

Tags: skype

My skype has 124 contacts. I don't want to remove any contacts, however I only want to be notified of when some people go online. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [VoiceGear contact alerter for Skype](http://www.industrydynamics.ca/skype_plugins.php). Using this you are able to set up notification with some extended options.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you could do this trough normal means. But you can do this through [Skype4Py API](https://github.com/awahlig/skype4py), or you could install [sevabot](http://sevabot-skype-bot.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) and program it to email/send you a message when person X logs on.